# Mimic a leadership metrics for management users

Tags: database, authorization, access-control

I have role based access control to my applications. I have team leader application where team leader with valid role can view their teams performance metrics. Now my top management wants to get a view of the team leader aka they want to mimic a particular team leader to see what they can see.

I am planning to add a table, which captures the

management user id to mimicking team leader user id,

so when i am validating the user, i can check this table and bring the correct view.

Is this a good approach ? Suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have role based access control to my applications.

In this case, `management user` is just another role, exactly as `team leader` or `ordinary user`.

You therefore should extend your access control to the new role without tricks and mimics. If the current way is not able to cope with composite roles, this is definitively something you should implement, but into the basic blocs of your access control.

But if you now start to add a special mimicking table that does access control for management user very differently from anything else, and if you start to switch views when you didn’t use this mechanism before, then it’s no longer “***role based***” but “***ad-hoc growing wild***”.

So yes: unless you omitted some key facts that could justify its rationale, the envisaged approach does unfortunately not seem to be a reliable, maintainable, future-proof approach.

Comment: The metrics are on the leader, it wont show up under the management user, thats why want to mimic management user as the leader so they can see the same view?

Comment: The manager user already has the admin role defined, but their view is going to be different from the leader view, leader view shows the statistics which is collected only under the leader

Comment: @tamilgirl I understand. Now, what happens when a leader leads two teams?

Comment: all the metrics will show up under that leader so that is not a problem, its just that management wants to see a view of the team leader

Comment: Even while testing as a developer i need to mimic the leader to do the development too, what is the best way to approach this?

Comment: @tamilgirl Sound separation of concerns suggest to separate the definition of the metric reporting from the access control issue. So reporting should be based on reporting objectives and data available. If you have  a leader with two different teams (e.g his normal team and temporarily the team of a colleague who resigned) team metrics should still be defined by team, even if by coincidence it’s the same leader. If you solve this at team leader level, you solve this at management level, since the manager just has to pic a team of interest.

Comment: @tamilgirl Switching views for testing purpose is one thing. But allowing such a switch for real use suggests that views (something that should be structural) are dependent on data that evolves (team leaders). This means to update db structure every time a new team leader is added? This seems not a good idea. Furthermore, over-reliance on views for access control is a frequent source of security issues.

Comment: Don't mimic the leader.

Comment: I am still confused on how to proceed, if I give list of leaders for management and they pick which leader data they want to see, is that more efficient way to handle this? How will I handle the role while testing the leader view ?

Comment: So for testing purpose I should hardcode a team leader badgeid to test their view then ? what is the best approach for this ?

Comment: @tamilgirl I would use same view for all, and add the leader as parameter to the query. For the testing, I’d create a test leader with test data to test exactly on the same situation the same code. You then can test if management selecting the same leader gives the same result. And then, on your test system you can assign yourself the management role to test whatever leader you want.

Comment: So basically test the view as a management role and select a leader to the view the leader view right ?

Comment: @tamilgirl could you provide a ER diagram of the section of your database design that manages the roles? (I'm assuming here you're using a relational database).

Comment: @tamilgirl yes, that was the idea, just in the reverse order. when you say view, you mean an sql view, isn’t it?  And the access control, do you do it at db level (aka GRANT) or in the code? And do clients have direct access to db or always via your system/service/server?

Comment: by view i mean the page view, like when an management user click on a team leader, they get the metrics of that team leader, when team leader is logged in they get their view of the page. does this make sense?

Comment: Thank you for your comments and thought process appreciate it